# Remove CA from before the $ in magento

Tags: magento

I am working on a magento site for Canada and so there is currently a CA$ before any price and we would like it just to appear as $. Is there a setting somewhere I can change to alter this without going through all of the code and doing it individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the directory `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data` and find the XML file for your locale.  If you're using the default local then I believe the file you want is `en.xml`.  Around line 5623 is the configuration for CAD currency.  Just change the symbol from CA$ to $.

Comment: If you can't find it in the en.xml file, check the root.xml file.

Comment: This is not the right solution for this task. You can check the file, there is no CA$ in en.xml